# How to extract the currency symbol?

Tags: datatool

Within the Datatool package, we find the currency data type.

A currency data type is a currency symbol followed by an integer or real number.

How can I extract the currency symbol out of a currency data ??

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\splitCurrency}[1]{%
    \noindent Splitting #1 into its value and symbol parts:
    \DTLifcurrency{#1}% Check: Is #1 currency?
    {% Check: #1 is currency !
        \\The value: \DTLconverttodecimal{#1}{\theValue} \theValue%
        \\The symbol: ??
    }{% Check: #1 is not currency !
        Not a currency !
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\splitCurrency{\$ 123}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running `\DTLifcurrency` or the internal equivalent `\@dtl@checknumerical`, the currency symbol is stored in `\@dtl@currency`, so you can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\getcurrencysymbol[2]{%
  \@dtl@checknumerical{#1}%
  \ifnum\@dtl@datatype=3\relax\let#2\@dtl@currency\else\def#2{??}\fi
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\splitCurrency}[1]{%
    \noindent Splitting #1 into its value and symbol parts:
    \DTLifcurrency{#1}% Check: Is #1 currency?
    {% Check: #1 is currency !
        \\The value: \DTLconverttodecimal{#1}{\theValue}\theValue%
        \\The symbol: \getcurrencysymbol{#1}{\theCurrency}\theCurrency
    }{% Check: #1 is not currency !
        Not a currency !
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\splitCurrency{\$ 123}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Anyway to force the extension within \getcurrencysymbol, so that I don't have to repeat \expandafter\theCurrency\relax on each use?

Comment: @JosephMarie I do not understand your question. Why would you have to repeat `\expandafter\theCurrency\relax`? `\expandafter\theCurrency\relax` would try to expand the non-expandable `\relax`, so `\expandafter` is useless here.

Comment: When I run \getcurrencysymbol{\$ 123}{\symbol}%
\DTLnewdbentry{data}{Symbol}{\symbol}%, I get an Error (Extra \else....).
When I do \DTLnewdbentry{data}{Symbol}{\expandafter\symbol\relax}%, there is no error.

Comment: @JosephMarie that's imho a bug in datatool, it fails if the value starts with something that could be a currency. Your \expandafter command hides this. You could also use `{\relax\symbol}`. I wrote Nicola a mail.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLnewcurrencysymbol{€}

\def\splitCurrency#1{\noindent Splitting #1 into its value and symbol parts: 
    \splitCurrencyA#1;}
\def\splitCurrencyA#1#2;{%
    \DTLifcurrency{#1#2}% Check: Is #1 currency?
    {% Check: #1 is currency !
        \\The value: \DTLconverttodecimal{#2}{\theValue} \theValue%
        \\The symbol: #1
    }{% Check: #1 is not currency !
        Not a currency !
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \splitCurrency{\$123}%

    \splitCurrency{€123}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant solution!
How does the argument parsing system knowns that he has to split into "text-value" at \def\splitCurrencyA#1#2; ?

Comment: The currency symbol is only one character or a macro (#1) and the rest until the ; will be the value (#2), that‘s all.